# How to add styling to element with liquid schema settings?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I would like to have a checkbox where if pressed it adds a line-through on an element.

This is my code:

```
{%- if section.settings.eventOver -%}
                      <p class="eventDate" id="eventID">{{ section.settings.date_picker | date: "%d-%m-%Y" }}</p>
              <script>
                      document.getElementById('eventID').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
              </script>
                    {%- endif -%}
```

and the schema code:

```
{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Event",
   "class": "Event",
  "settings": [
   {
        "type": "image_picker",
        "id": "image",
        "label": "event Image"
    },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "eventOver",
        "label": "Click if the event is passed",
        "default": false
    },
```

(I have only put the code for the necessary parts, I think)

Currently with this code, if the checkbox is clicked it adds the line through but it only does so for the first one. If I have 2 where I've clicked the checkbox, it only turns it on for the first one.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and without unecessary JS:

```
<p class="eventDate{% if section.settings.eventOver %} eventOver{% endif %}">
    {{ section.settings.date_picker | date: "%d-%m-%Y" }}
</p>

<style>
    .eventOver {text-decoration:line-through;}
</style>
```

Please note about your JS code that it ain't be more than one unique ID per document which probably explains your issue.